# usb cdc device driver

Tags: usb

I have CDC device. I develop driver for him.
Part of ini file:

```
[ClassInstall32]
CopyFiles=ClassInstall.CopyFiles
AddReg=ClassInstall.AddReg

[ClassInstall.CopyFiles]
My_USBDriver.dll,,,0x2000

[ClassInstall.AddReg]
HKR,,,,%DEVICEMANAGERCATEGORY%
HKR,,Icon,,"102"
HKR,,Installer32,,"My_USBDriver.dll,MyUSBPortsClassInstaller" 
HKR,,NoInstallClass,,1

[DriverInstall] 
include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=DriverInstall.CopyFiles
AddReg=DriverInstall.AddReg 

[DriverInstall.CopyFiles]
usbser.sys,,,0x2000

[DriverInstall.AddReg]
HKR,,DevLoader,,*ntkern 
HKR,,NTMPDriver,,%DRIVERFILENAME%.sys 

[DriverInstall.Services] 
AddService=usbser, 0x00000002, DriverService

[DriverService] 
DisplayName=%SERVICE% 
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\%DRIVERFILENAME%.sys
```

Installer function have code:

```
c->ConnectionIndex = iPort;
c->SetupPacket.bmRequest = 0x80;
c->SetupPacket.wValue = (USB_STRING_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE<<8)|descriptorNum;
c->SetupPacket.wLength = n;
Success = DeviceIoControl(
    hRoot,
    IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION,
    c, n,
    c, n,
    &returnBytes,
    NULL);
///Sometime GetLastError == 31 // Device not working
```

This code normal work on desctop(PC) always, but only sometime work on laptop(notebook) during the installation the device(installation function calling by system). OS of these mashines is Windows7.
BUT if i call installation function from my progrm(created for debuggin) this code always work correctly (on notebook and on pc).
Does anyone have ideas on this issue?

Comment: Error code 31 means "This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device." - Is the machine running a 64-bit OS? If so, it'll need driver signature verification switched off and test signing enabled.

Comment: My actions: 1) bcdedit /set testsigning on                            2)reboot                                                            3)press f8 on load and select Don't need driver check                            But this is not help me.

Answer (score 0):

You said Desktop and Laptop, but I don't think the shape of the computer matters. Is one 32 bit OS and the other is 64 bit? I don't see the 64bit INF section.